# Is there an easy way in p5.js to draw a transparent shape without having the outline being drawn onto that shape?

Tags: javascript, opacity, p5.js

I am trying to draw an opaque shape on top of a colorful background in p5.js. So I give both the fill color and the stroke color an alpha value. The problem is that the outline of the shape is partly drawn onto the shape. Because of the opaque stroke, this makes it look like there is two outlines with different colors. Here is an example:

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(60, 60);
}

function draw() {
    background(255);

    fill(127,127);
    stroke(50,127);
    strokeWeight(5);

    rect(10,10,40,40);
}
```

What I get is [this square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BsVQ.png) which appears to have an inner dark gray and an outer light gray bounding box.

Is there an easy way to prevent this from happening? I know I could draw the shape "twice" (first the fill and then the outline a little bit further out), but
I am trying to draw a rather complicated polygon, so I would have to adjust all the vertex coordinates of the outer shape which would be pretty annoying to work out.

I have already tried the different blendModes, but they didn't seem to be able to solve my problem.

Comment: *"I am trying to draw an opaque shape on top of a colorful background [...]"* - Why is the outline transparent?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because you have a stroke weight of 5, which is drawn from the edge of the shape, in both directions. So some of the stroke is on the inside of the shape, and some of the stroke is on the outside.

I don't know of a way to change this setting. I tried playing with `strokeCap` and `strokeJoin` but nothing solved the problem.

One option that occurs to me is drawing a scaled-down version of the shape with a stroke weight of 1. That would look something like this:

```js
let shapeGraphics;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(260, 260);
  
  // draw a scaled-down version of the shape
  shapeGraphics = createGraphics(8, 8);
  shapeGraphics.fill(127, 127);
  shapeGraphics.stroke(50, 127);
  shapeGraphics.rect(0, 0, 8, 8);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  noSmooth();
  
  // draw a scaled-up version of the graphics
  image(shapeGraphics, 10, 10, 40, 40); 
}
```

[image: shape with border]

If that doesn't work, then the only other option I can think of is to calculate the outer edges yourself and draw the shape twice, like you mentioned.